# Python. PyQt. QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt

Почему `setFixedSize()` не работает?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.window.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        self.Scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.Scroll.setWidget(self.window)
        self.Scroll.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.window.setFixedSize(300, 300) - РАБОТАЕТ
```

Я раскрасил виджеты, чтобы вы увидели где-какой виджет.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f55;')

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.window = QWidget()
        self.window.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        self.window.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ff5;')

        self.Scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.Scroll.setStyleSheet('background-color: #55f;')
        self.Scroll.setWidget(self.window)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.Scroll)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]